# Computing gradient over all examples in gradient descent

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent

I am studying about Gradient Descent and Stochastic Gradient Descent, and the text says that one of the advantages of sgd over gd is, that gd can be computationally expensive for large datasets. In particular, it says that in gd, the gradient is calculated for all of the data points and in sgd on a random batch.

My question is, Why do we need to calculate any other point except for the one we are currently at?

[Let's take a Quadratic function for example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raH80.jpg)

If we are currently at x1, and we want to go towards the minimum, why would we even care about the derivative in x2? it's not like we are going to say "oh yeah at x2 its steeper let's go there" .. it is also not implemented in code in any way.

Also in sgd, it calculates a PART of the datapoints, which is still not understood why do we need any other point than the current 1? why not calculate 1 point at a time if we step on it instead of calculating all?

Thank you and please give feedback if I can become clearer in my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing the current value of the parameters at which the gradient is calculated with the data points. Consider the simple model:

$$y_i = a + bx_i + u_i$$

and let us choose to minimize the sum of the squared residuals as the objective function:

$$\min_{\hat{a},\hat{b}} \sum_i^N (y_i - \hat{a} - \hat{b}x_i)^2$$

For any given value of the pair $(\hat{a},\hat{b})$, we can calculate the gradient of the objective function at that value, but to do so requires summing over all $N$ data points.  What if $N = 1,000,000$ or more?  SGD suggests sampling the data points and calculating an estimate of the gradient based on the sample, which might be, for example, $1,000$ data points (in our simple example.)  It will take more iterations to get close to the optimum, but each iteration is a lot less costly from a compute perspective.

SGD is an example of [stochastic approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_approximation), something you might look up so as to get a better idea of under what conditions it works and why.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer! I think i understand it now..
So if im not mistaken, for a given pair of parameters , to calculate the loss of the mentioned parameters, GD sums all the data (lets call it the population just for better understanding) and with SGD you sample from the data (sample from the population) and use it as a representative for the population? like using the mean vs sample average and standard deviation vs standard error?

Comment: Then please accept it, so future readers with a similar question will know there was a "successful" answer to it here.

Comment: Yes, exactly so.  You are, in effect, forming an estimate of the gradient at each step rather than calculating the exact gradient at each step.

Comment: Thank you so much mate, much appreciated!